# PHP - Empty field error handling

Tags: php, forms

I have a form to create an account and it redirects to my php page to check the form for empty fields and insert the data.

I'm using `empty();` to check if the fields are empty and as error handling I simply use an echo, now my question is if I can do this in a somewhat better way, because my php form check page does not have any design applied so the error handling is just on a blank page.

Comment: you could use jQuey to check the fields' values and then only submit the form if all are filled in.

Comment: Skugga: I think its a bad practice to do validation of form at server side, better use javascript in your form , to validate all the fields and then send the final complete value to server side script(php).

Comment: @dreamweiver I hope you're not implying to skip server-side validation entirely?!

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys, I will take a look into both jQuery and Javascript. ;)

Comment: skugga : Not exactly , validation which doesnt require server side functionality like database access etc., you can perform all of them at client side itself using Jquery lib(javascript). this improves your site performance

Comment: Skugga: Jquery is a lib of Javascript :) its not different things ,happy coding :)

Comment: You can use any sort of javascript based solution to improve the handling of your site.
BUT: You can't ever trust the validation made by jQuery or any other javascript because it's made on client side! And you never can trust any data that comes fromt the client. In addition you _always_ have to validate _all passed_ data on server side (eg. in PHP).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the fields in your form are input text fields (Add class "requiredField") to these.Make you Submit button disabled as the empty form loads.

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input.requiredField:text").bind("keyup change", function() {

        updateSaveButton();
    });

});

function updateSaveButton() {
if ( $(".requiredField:text").filter(function() {return $(this).val().match(/^\s*$/);}).length) {
$("#submit").button({
            disabled : true
        });
} else {
 $("#submit").button({                                                                                                                                                                                      
                 disabled : false                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    });
}


}
```

Submit is the id of the submit button and button is a part of jQuery UI. However if you are not using jQuery UI you could simply add the disabled attribute . For Eg:

```
$("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled"); {to add disabled attribute}
$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled"); {to remove disabled attribute}
```

Since Your Submit button will remain disabled, the user will not be able to submit any form. the Submit button will also remain disabled when the user enters only spaces as the values of any text field

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion empty() is the best way to check input in general

```
 if( empty( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) ) {

      $error = 'Please enter a user name';
 }
```

In the best case you do this

```
 $username = !empty( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) ? trim( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) : '';

 if( empty( $username ) ) $error = 'Please insert a user name';
 if( strlen( $username ) < 3 ) $error = 'Username needs 3 characters';
 //etc...
```

This will make sure that the user doesn't just provide white-spaces to feed your requested input

There are several methods to handle the input.

1) Redirect your form to the same page and handle the input above the output

```
 $error = '';
 if( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] ) === 'post' ) {


      //handle user input and fill $error if needed

      if( empty( $error ) ) {
          //success
      }

 }

 ?>
 <form action="thissite.php">
      <?php if( !empty( $error ) ) :?><span class="error"><?=$error?></span><?php endif; ?>
      <...rest of the form...>
 </form>
```

2) You can handle it with AJAX

Submit your Form via AJAX (see jQuery's [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [$.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), this well help you a lot), receive a JSON string that contains either a success state or the error. Parse this and insert error elements in your form accordingly

3) (Worst way imo) Go to a new page, show the errors and redirect to the form again if there are errors

Submit the form to a new page that handles the input, output styled error messages and put a link that either proceeds you (on success) or brings you back to the form (on error)

Answer (score 0):

The best things you can do, is to do it with exceptions (in case that you use class to work with the registration.

For instance, you would have class like that

```
class Account {
   public function register($username, $password, $mail) {
      if(empty($username)) throw new RegistrationException("Username is empty.");
      // and so on
  }
}
```

Then in a registration place, you`ll do something like that

```
try {
    $account = new Account();
} catch(RegistrationException $e) {
    // print the message out
    // $e->getMessage() will return the parameter of new RegistrationException(...)
}
```

Then, just create an exception class that extends exception

```
class RegistrationException extends Exception {}
```

In case, that you will have a client-side validation (javascript/jQuery), do NOT forgot to have validation on server-side (php) too. If you would not have, user will remove the authentication rules and break in (with no username, with invalid characters, ...)